# Processing: Split screen = 1 canvas?

Tags: split, screen, processing

I'm working on a visualization for a 7680x1080 projection.
[image: visualization]

The production company wants me to out put this as 3840x2160.
[image: output]

How would I do this in Processing so that Processing still sees this as 1 big canvas and I can have seamless graphics across the entire width?

Thanks!
Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Processing drawing is done in a `PGraphics` and `PImage` object (learn more here: https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html)

You can then read the pixels you put in your PGraphics canvas and split them out in 2 PImage objects

Example:

```
int w = 500;
int h = 500;
PImage topCanvas;
PImage bottomCanvas;
PGraphics mainCanvas;

void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(w, h, P3D);
  mainCanvas = createGraphics(w, h, P2D);

  mainCanvas.beginDraw();
  for(int i=0; i<w; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
        mainCanvas.stroke( random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255)); 
        mainCanvas.point(i, j); 
     } 
  }
  mainCanvas.endDraw();
} 

void draw(){

  topCanvas = mainCanvas.get(0,0,w, h/2);
  bottomCanvas = mainCanvas.get(0,h/2,w, h/2);

  image(topCanvas, 0, 0);
  image(bottomCanvas, 0, h/2);

}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for! Will play around with this a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Processing already is one big canvas. You control what you draw and where you draw it.

You could just keep track of your viewport size and location, then split up your drawing into functions:

```java
float viewportTwoX;
float viewportTwoY;

float viewportWidth;
float viewportHeight;

void setup() {
  size(768, 108);
  viewportTwoX = width/2;
  viewportTwoY = 0;
  viewportWidth = width/2;
  viewportHeight = height;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  drawViewportOne();
  drawViewportTwo();
}

void drawViewportOne() {
  fill(64);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
  fill(255);
  text("viewport 1", viewportWidth/2, viewportHeight/2);
}

void drawViewportTwo() {
  translate(viewportTwoX, viewportTwoY); 

  fill(128);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
  fill(255);
  text("viewport 2", viewportWidth/2, viewportHeight/2);
}
```

Then if you want to change the location of the second viewport, you just have to change the values of those variables:

```java
void setup() {
  size(384, 216);
  viewportTwoX = 0;
  viewportTwoY = height/2;
  viewportWidth = width;
  viewportHeight = height/2;
}
```